# Delete row/column from matrix/array and retain remaining column and row names in R

Tags: r, matrix, row, erase

I have the following code:

```
# Load BayesFactor package
library(BayesFactor)

# Call raceDolls data
data(raceDolls)

# Attribute data to matrix
raceDolls2 <- raceDolls
```

Calling `raceDolls2` gives the following output:

```
                    White child Black child
Same-race doll               50          48
Different-race doll          21          41
```

`class(raceDolls2)` gives the following: `[1] "matrix" "array"`

Now I would like to "simply" remove a row, so I do:

```
# Remove row 'Different-race doll' from raceDolls2
raceDolls2 <- raceDolls2[ !rownames(raceDolls2) == 'Different-race doll']
```

By calling `raceDolls2`, I expected the following output:

```
                    White child Black child
Same-race doll               50          48
```

However I get this:

```
[1] 50 48
```

And `class(raceDolls2)` now gives the following: `"numeric"`

Alternatively, when I try to remove a column, I used:

```
# Load BayesFactor package
library(BayesFactor)

# Call raceDolls data
data(raceDolls)

# Attribute data to matrix
raceDolls3 <- raceDolls

# Remove column 'White child' from raceDools3
raceDolls3 <- raceDolls3[ !colnames(raceDolls3) == 'White child']
```

I expect this:

```
                    Black child
Same-race doll               48
Different-race doll          41
```

However, I get this:

```
[1] 21 41
```

I at least expected something like:

```
48 41
```

My question:

- What function do I have to use so the data and attributes are preserved when removing a row